# TYPO3 IRRE open record is extremly slow

Tags: mysql, typo3

We have created a T3 extension where each record can have a couple of related event dates. The event dates are declared as IRRE recordings.

Now as the event dates getting more it takes up to 50 secs. to open a basic record in the Backend, frontend is fast as usual.

Right now there are 600 base records and 17K IRRE records. Things started to slow down at about 8K event dates.
Anyone an idea how to speed things up?

thx for your help

Comment: Just for correct understanding: Opening an IRRE record inside a base record is slow or already the opening of the base records is slow?

Comment: Opening the base record is slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IRRE wasn't the bottleneck of that performance issue.
We added a label_userFunc to display a formatted date as label of the IRRE entries but called the userfunction in TCA with

```
label_userFunc (doesn't work with IRRE)
```

but it must be called with

```
formattedLabel_userFunc (works with IRRE)
```

as only that one works with IRRE.
For other performance problems consider matin his answer:
in TCA set collapseAll = 1 and expandSingle =1

Answer (score 0):

for fronteand enable lazy load in domain model and disable collaps all in tca for backend:

```
'config' => array(
            'type' => 'inline',
            'foreign_table' => 'tx_xxx_domain_model_yyy',
            'foreign_field' => 'rrrr',
            'foreign_sortby' => 'sorting',
            'maxitems'      => 9999,
            'appearance' => array(
                'expandSingle' => 1,
                'collapseAll' => 1,
                'levelLinksPosition' => 'top',
                'showSynchronizationLink' => 1,
                'showPossibleLocalizationRecords' => 1,
                'useSortable' => 1,
                'showAllLocalizationLink' => 1
            ),
```